# PACT Bamboo Test Result Parser

Tags: pact

I am using pact-provider-gradle project and am outputting the results of our contract tests to both the console and to a JSON report.   Unfortunately their is no plugin for PACT on Bamboo.   Is there another way around this?  It would be much easier if the gradle project for the provider allowed you to output results in XML so I could use the junit parser.

Answer (score 0):

Can you raise a feature request in pact-jvm please? Are you interested in contributing? Ron Holshausen, the maintainer, would be happy to point you in the right direction.